# Angular: Images not loading in production

Tags: angular

I have my images in src/assets/images/ directory and in html i am referring to them  like below

```
<img src="assets/images/penndot-logo-full.png" />
```

This works fine in dev mode. But in prod it give 404 error. I have built my application using the below command

```
ng build --prod --deploy-url /myapp --base-href /myapp
```

[This](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#the-base-tag) section explains that in prod angular will resolve the image paths with what is present in base-href tag. I checked my compiled index.html page and the base-href points to /myapp but still the images are not being resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular makes use of the base href to tell router how to compose navigation URLs. If your application exists at the root, then you can use / as the href value as shown below.

```
<base href="/">
```

If you build the project the Angular project for the production environment using the default values you will get the following index.html generated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>some title</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

but as i see your application may exist in sub folder in production mode called myapp

so you need to make your base href like this `<base href="/myapp/">`

so the missing piece in your command is the ending slash in `/myapp/` as you see below this from angular official documentation:

[image: ending slash in base href]

besides that you can merge both application base for router & base for assets if they got the same base like `/myapp/` so no need to specify deploy-url:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /myapp/
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but when i use <base href="/"> then the page doesn't load.